# No LoadComplete for a MasterPage?

Tags: asp.net

With `AutoEventWireUp` set to false, I would normally set a `Page_Finalize` like this:

```
Include(Self.LoadComplete, Self.Page_Finalize); //Delphi
```

`LoadComplete` however, doesn't seem to be available on a MasterPage and my `Page_Finalize` obviously doesn't get called.

What am I meant to do to free objects in the master page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LoadComplete` method is simply **not** a member of `MasterPage`, but of `Page`.

There are several reasons for this, including the fact that the *orchestrator* of page life cycle is `Page` class itself.

It has three event-related methods: `PreLoad`, `Load`, `LoadComplete`. During `Load`, the `Load` event of children controls is triggered.

While a master page contains (by means of *layout*) the contents of the page, the page contains the `MasterPage` by means of objects, since the `Page` is the `IHttpHandler` that responds to HTTP requests in ASP.NET.

Briefly, you **cannot** override (I don't know Delphi, is that some kind of override?) `OnLoadComplete` in `MasterPage` as it's not defined. Only `OnLoad`

Comment: Thanks for that. How would I go about freeing objects then that are used within the the masterpage?

Comment: You should go for Dispose event, or just any event that is **subsequent** to the phases of life cycle in which you need to access data. I remember I answered a question about this but can't find it. If you are sure that you no longer need data after load, you can free objects earlier in PreRender, which is subsequent to Load

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but adding a method to the Page.LoadComplete event from the master page seems to work.

Within the master page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Page.LoadComplete += Page_LoadComplete;
}

protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // do stuff on LoadComplete in the master page
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly, this does work, even though the event is not available in the editor, at runtime it actually adds the event handler and works as expected.